# How to partition based on two columns in Oracle/sql

Tags: sql, oracle, window-functions

Please help me with the following

Question:

```
+------+----------+
| Name | Sub-name |
+------+----------+
| A    | x        |
| A    | x        |
| B    | x        |
| A    | y        |
| B    | y        |
+------+----------+
```

Desired Result:

```
+------+----------+-------+
| Name | Sub-name | Count |
+------+----------+-------+
| A    | x        |     2 |
| A    | x        |     2 |
| B    | x        |     1 |
| A    | y        |     1 |
| B    | y        |     1 |
+------+----------+-------+
```

Three columns Name, Subname, Count

I want to partition based on both name and subname.

Comment: Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). What have you tried?

Comment: Im sorry if the question I asked is not proper.
I tried count(Name) OVER (PARTITION  BY Sub-NAME) AS Count

Comment: Okay, so what does that output that is incorrect? (FYI that is the sort of thing you should have in your question - people on here will help you debug code that you've already written, but they're less likely to just write it for you.)

Comment: not exactly sure what you are after but it sounds you want to check out rollup or cube.

Comment: Seems like you're on the right track with `count() over ()`, but the partition specification looks a bit off.

Comment: Maybe show your actual column names (the DDL)?  if your field name is really Sub-NAME then you need double quotes

Comment: okay,
my original field names are Report_Name and Target_type...both of which need quotes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/caba4/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE test ( Name, "Sub-name" ) AS
          SELECT 'A', 'x' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'A', 'x' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'B', 'x' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'A', 'y' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'B', 'y' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT Name,
       "Sub-name",
       COUNT( 1 ) OVER ( PARTITION BY "Sub-name", Name ) AS "Count"
FROM   test
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/caba4/1/0)**:

```
| NAME | Sub-name | Count |
|------|----------|-------|
|    A |        x |     2 |
|    A |        x |     2 |
|    B |        x |     1 |
|    A |        y |     1 |
|    B |        y |     1 |
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

select name, sub_name, count(name) over (partition by name, sub_name) as count from table

Answer (score 0):

select ra.Name,ra.sub-name,ta.count from table ra
inner join
(select Name,sub-name,count(*) from table
group by Name,sub-name)ta
on ra.Name=ta.Name
on ra.sub-name=ta.sub-name
order by sub-name desc

Really i don't understand why we need to use partition for this solution.Even the above join query works fine...hope it should....